# Install multiple instance of same Windows app on same device

Tags: deployment, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have a Windows store app need to be deployed to same device as multiple instances(client wise). App has a store association so I can't change the

```
Package Name or `Package Display Name`
```

Please help me with how to do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install 2 versions of same Windows 10 Universal App in the same OS instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307788/install-2-versions-of-same-windows-10-universal-app-in-the-same-os-instance)

Answer (score -1):

I am sorry to disappoint you, but there is no way to deploy multiple versions of the same app to one device. The only possible scenario is having a Release and Debug version at the same time but that is nothing you can provide your customers with.

Comment: Yes, you can. Right click on the project -> Store -> 'Associate app with the store', then associate your app wit ha new name. This will generate a new store key which recognizes your app uniquely. To distinguish apps, in the Package.appxmanifest file Change the 'Display Name' and 'Short Name'.