# Install 2 versions of same Windows 10 Universal App in the same OS instance

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

We are developing a Windows 10 Universal app. Currently, there are 2 branches of the app code, MAIN and DEV. We would like to be able to install (and run) both builds on the same OS instance at the same time.

Right now, we do not see any other way of doing this than having a separate VM for each app build, but this is not our preference.

Does anyone have any experience with this type of challenge, and does anyone know if this is even possible from technology standpoint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each package must have a distinct PFN (Package Family Name) listed in the package.appxmanifest.xml if you want them to be installed on the same computer.

There's no way to sideload multiple versions of the same package.

So, use different PFNs for each branch (probably easiest, if done from your build system), or explore your VM options.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project -> Store -> 'Associate app with the store', then associate your app wit ha new name. This will generate a new store key which recognizes your app uniquely. To distinguish apps, in the Package.appxmanifest file Change the 'Display Name' and 'Short Name'.

Answer (score 0):

Package.appxmanifest

```
-> Right Click -> View Code (F7) -> Change Identity Name to something else 

-> OR Double Click -> Packaging -> Package Name to something else

-> Debug/Run/Deploy without replacing existing installed version (that had different identity name.
```